# How to zip files every one hour in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory (say) **data/Test/** I receive **.dat** files every few minutes but only at the end of say 2hrs i want to zip all the files that are there and then sleep for 2 hrs again repeat the cycle.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a question for Super User (or possibly Server Fault) and a job for Cron.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this maybe:

```
while : ; do sleep 7200; tar czf /tmp/data.tgz /data/Test; done &
```

This method has advantages and disadvantages versus cron. This method is quick & easy with no problems with PATH or permissions or illegal characters in crontab. The disadvantage is that it will not persist if you reboot or logout.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a cron job to create the zip file every two hours like this .

enter crontab -e and then enter

0 0-23/2 * * *   /path/to/your/script/to/create/zip.sh

Answer (score 0):

Another way (works until the next shutdown):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# this script executes, and re-schedules itself every 2 hours

nb_hours=2

do_something () {
   ........
}

# main:

cd -P "${direname "$0"}"

#do something:
do_something

#and schedule yourself to re-run in $nb_hours hours :
echo "$(basename "$0")" | at now + ${nb_hours} hours
```

Note: You'll need to start this script once per boot (for example using a startup file)
  (so the crontab is probably better suited, but I wanted to show that option which has it's good side too : you could have the script decide to reschedule itself OR NOT, depending on some condition, for example (well, you could too in the cron'ed script by adding conditions at the beginning...) )